# Is the following usage of について natural?

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax

This is a sentence I came across when I was reading about 書体 on Wikipedia:

> 書体（しょたい）とは、一定の文字体系のもとにある文字について、それぞれの字体が一貫した特徴と独自の様式を備えた字形として、表現されているものをいう

I feel について here is used as は (i.e. a topic marker) instead of when you want to say that the topic of a talk, discussion, consultation, question, etc. "is about ~". Is this usage of について correct?

Comment: Well, it’s definitely not an example of good writing.

Comment: It makes the scentenc  rather difficult to parse

Comment: Tbh in that sentence, if I had to replace について with something else, I'd use が rather than は.

Comment: Gui imamura why ?

Answer (score 0):

It is something you encounter exclusively in writing. In that sense, it is neither unnatural nor incorrect.

It could be comparable to English *regarding, as for*.

The 「特定の文字体系のもとにある文字について、それぞれの字体が一貫した特徴と独自の様式を備えた字形として、表現されている」 part alone literally translates like

> Regarding 特定の文字体系のもとにある文字, each 字体 is represented as 一貫した特徴と独自の様式を備えた字形

Another difficulty may be that the above structure must be drastically changed due to the last ものをいう if you really want to translate it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how  it is changed

Comment: @user50156 I'm not sure of the terminology, but one possibility would be like 書体 is a set of representations where each glyph(字体) of characters in in a particular system is expressed as 一貫した特徴と独自の様式を備えた字形. I think you need to understand the difference of 字体 and 字形 in order to translate it precisely (which I don't).

Comment: @goldenlight, sundowner, but "regarding, as for", is the original meaning of として (i.e. the same as "is about ~") that OP seems to differentiate from the usage in their particular example, isn't it?

Comment: @jarmanso7 I guess it's basically the same thing. として iniicates *is about*/*topic* or context. Structurally it is not so problematic. For example, 屈折語とは、言語について、語形の変化があるものをいう should be a natural enough example (linguistic precision aside). The quote is simply a bad definition with vague terms (at least not self contained).